# как вывести на экран `typedef unsigned char`?

Tags: c

как вывести на экран  `typedef unsigned char`  ? 
У меня чёт не выходит не монимаю что я делаю не так.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int len = 8;
    typedef unsigned char data[8];

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)  
        data[i] = ((i + 10)*2)/3; // первая попытка заполнить массив 
    memset(data, '1', 8); // вторая попытка заполнить массив

     printf("DATA : ");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        printf(" [%s] ", data[i]);}
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        printf(" [%u] ", data[i]);}
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf(" [%d] ", data[i]);
    printf("\n");
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            printf(" %02X", data[i]);
    printf("\n");

    // тут всё работает (если код сверху закоментировать)
    char data1[len];
        for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
            data1[i] = ((i + 10)*2)/3;
    printf("DATA1 : ");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        printf(" [%u] ", data1[i]);}
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Этот пример, попытка эмуляции одной ошибки.

`int-ll64.h`

`typedef unsigned char __u8;`

`can.h`

```
struct canfd_frame {
    canid_t can_id;  /* 32 bit CAN_ID + EFF/RTR/ERR flags */
    __u8    len;     /* frame payload length in byte */
    __u8    flags;   /* additional flags for CAN FD */
    __u8    __res0;  /* reserved / padding */
    __u8    __res1;  /* reserved / padding */
    __u8    data[CANFD_MAX_DLEN] __attribute__((aligned(8)));
};
```

именно `__u8    data[CANFD_MAX_DLEN] __attribute__((aligned(8)));` пытаюсь эмулировать. Так как `data[CANFD_MAX_DLEN]` не получается вывести через `printf();`,

а обычные переменные из этой структуры  прекрасно выводятся

пример :

```
void processFrame(const struct canfd_frame& frame) {
    printf("CAN ID : %d \n", frame.can_id);
    printf("LEN : %d \n", frame.len);
}
```

Comment: Напишите точно, чего именно вы хотите добиться. Если буквально понимать ваш вопрос, то ответ на него будет таким: `printf("typedef unsigned char");`

Comment: "typedef unsigned char data[8];" - бред какой-то. Если хотите "эмулировать", то должно быть `typedef unsigned char __u8; __u8 data[8];`

Comment: Все, я понял. вам нужно вывести `__u8    data[CANFD_MAX_DLEN] __attribute__((aligned(8)));`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko да

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ответ  на "эмуляторе"

вот код :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/types.h>

int main()
{
    int len = 8;
//    unsigned char data[8];
    typedef unsigned char __u8; __u8 data[8];

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        data[i] = ((i + 10)*2)/3;
//    memset(data, '1', 8);

     printf("DATA : ");
//    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
//        printf(" [%s] ", data[i]);}
//    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        printf(" [%u] ", data[i]);}
//    printf("\n");
//    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
//        printf(" [%d] ", data[i]);
//    printf("\n");
//      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
//            printf(" %02X", data[i]);
//    printf("\n");

    // тут всё работает
    char data1[len];
        for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
            data1[i] = ((i + 10)*2)/3;
//    memset(data1, '1', 8);
    printf("DATA1 : ");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        printf(" [%u] ", data1[i]);}
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В код внес поправки :

```
void processFrame(const struct canfd_frame& frame) {
    int len = 0; len = frame.len;
    unsigned char data[8];

    printf("CAN ID : %d \n", frame.can_id);
    printf("frame.can_id : %03X \n", frame.can_id );
    printf("LEN : %d \n", frame.len); 
    printf("len = %d \n", len);
    printf("DATA : ");
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf(" [%u] ", frame.data[i]);
    printf("\n", len);    
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        data[i] = frame.data[i];
    printf("data : ");    
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf(" [%u] ", data[i]);        
    printf("\n ---------------- \n");
//     for (int i = 0; i < frame.len; ++i)
//        {
//            printf(" %02X", frame.data[i]);
//        }
    //---//
}
```

Всё работает :3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

`typedef` это создание нового имени составного типа, а вы используете как переменную.

В этом примере логично убрать слово `typedef` совсем.

Или

typedef unsigned char [8] datatype; datatype data;

Comment: у вы сложно, потому как это "попытка" эмуляции одного объявления

Comment: обновил вопрос :3

Comment: Вообще-то `typedef` не создает новый тип, он создает синоним. На практике разница очень существенная.

Comment: Тем не менее это иллюстрирует что контретно в коде не так.

Comment: @freim можно исправить ответ, суть та же